# ORA-01704: string literal too long in oracle 10g

Tags: java, oracle

I am getting `ORA-01704: string literal too long` error when there is more than 4000 chars for the field RAWDATA. The data type is CLOB. I am using java 1.4 and oracle 10g.

```
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO RAWDATA_EQUIFAX (REQ_ID, BUREAU_CODE, RAWDATA, RESP_TIME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

stmt.setInt(1, RequestID);
stmt.setString(2, bureau_code);
stmt.setString(3, rawData);
stmt.setTimestamp(4, new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
stmt.executeUpdate();
conn.commit();
```

Comment: Which is expected: a VARCHAR2 column has a max length of 4000, and this also stands true for using literals in queries. Use a CLOB parameter.

Comment: its CLOB in oracle, still getting the error

Comment: There's an Java / Oracle CLOB example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use [`PreparedStatement#setString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) to set a `Clob`.
There is a [`PreparedStatement#setClob()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setClob%28int,%20java.sql.Clob%29) method that you can use instead.

Comment: I just made it stmt.setClob(3, rawData); and I got error: The method setClob(int, Clob) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, String)

Comment: There are other `setClob()` methods. Have you tried `setClob(3, new StringReader(rawData))`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this to set Clob parameter to the PreparedStatement:

```
Clob clob = conn.createClob();
clob.setString(1, rawData);
stmt.setClob(3, clob);
clob.free();
```